# Set file path instead of "no file chosen" using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, file-io

Hiii Everyone,

I want to set 'source URL' via jquery to input type="file".I want to replace 'No file chosen' with specific Url.

```
$("#audio0").attr("src", url);
```

I want to set this URl attribute with

```
<input type="file" name="audio_i0" id="audio_i0"/>
```

I had tried with set attribute of "title" and also tried with label set attribute but nothing is working out.Please anyone help me to get out of this Issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you cant set file in input

Comment: Sorry I couldnt get u

Comment: My url='blob:http://localhost/3e61e886-fc12-4ab7-ab5d-745604d96564' has path like this I want to set this path instead of "no file chosen"

Comment: you cant set a file as default value for input type file

Comment: this might make clearer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html

Comment: Then whats the way to clear this issue.Actually I have <audio id="audio0" src="blob:http://localhost/3e61e886-fc12-4ab7-ab5d-745604d96564">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138496/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-guradio).